# Symfony 5 - multiple guard authentications - home page authenticate user

Tags: php, symfony, web-application-firewall

i'm quite new in symfony and what i'm trying to do is multiple login authentications.
I've got already two tables COMPANY and CANDIDATE. Both of them has different login form, controller and authenticator. Authentication process is going fine, and authorizate my both users, so firewalls works fine expect the last one "main" with pattern "/^". Home page (what means index by the way) doesn't authenticate user and see as "ANON" like by defualt....

this is my "security.yaml"

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\Candidates:
        algorithm: auto
    App\Entity\Companies:
        algorithm: auto


# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    candidates:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Candidates
            property: email
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    companies:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Companies
            property: email

    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [candidates, companies]
    
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false



    candidate:
        pattern: ^/candidate/.*
        anonymous: true
        lazy: true
        provider: candidates
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\CandidatesAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_candidate_logout
            # where to redirect after logout
            target: /
        form_login:
            login_path: /candidate/login
            check_path: /candidate/login
        #     username_parameter: "login_form[email]"
        #     password_parameter: "login_form[password]"

    company:
        pattern: ^/company/.*
        anonymous: true
        lazy: true
        provider: companies
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\CompaniesAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_company_logout
            # where to redirect after logout
            target: /
        form_login:
            login_path: /company/login
            check_path: /company/login
            # username_parameter: "login_form[email]"
            # password_parameter: "login_form[password]"
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider: chain_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\CandidatesAuthenticator
                - App\Security\CompaniesAuthenticator
            entry_point: App\Security\CandidatesAuthenticator 
        # logout:
        #     path: app_logout
        #     where to redirect after logout
        #     target: /

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way tocontrol access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

what i did wrong ?

Comment: 5.1 has made some [simplifications to the security system](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-updated-security-system).  You should be using things like [LoginFormAuthenticators](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) instead of the older form_login stuff.  Get that sorted out then maybe it will become clearer as to what is happening.  [This article](http://wouterj.nl/2020/04/authenticators-new-symfony-security) might also help.

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't really solved my problem, i need 3 seperate firewalls and one must be defualt for all routes that authenticate user, how to do this ?

Comment: I guess I am not understanding the question.  Why do you think you need three firewalls?  Normally only one is needed for the application level.  The access control section is used for authorization.

Comment: just 1 ??? So how to deal with login multiple users from different DB ? I need admin panel on backend and frontend pages too. so can you explain me how to deal with firewalls and authentications users ?

Comment: That brings us back to my original comment about using guard authenticators.  If you check the example you will note that each authenticator specifies the login url that it deals with.  No more login_path and check_path.  Furthermore, each authenticator has it's own getUser method so no need to specify providers any more.  The result is just the main firewall with the two authenticators specified.  Create a new project and then walk through the 5.1 example.  When reading the docs you will have to ignore all the old stuff about form_login.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem still is that i can not set 2 authenticators in one firewall, it just doesn't work. I can paste the whole code if you need...

Comment: Probably be too much code.  If you create a fresh project and add just enough code to demonstrate the actual problem with using a single firewall then you could check it in to github and I'll take a look.  Otherwise, hopefully someone else will come along and help you.

Comment: This FAQ on [multiple firewalls](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#frequently-asked-questions) might help as well.